# How can I style an event overlay with terraform?

Tags: events, terraform, terraform-provider-datadog

I am trying to create an event overlay with terraform,
so far this works

> ```
>   event {
> ```

```
      q = "sources:test tags:1"
    }
```

The issue is that I want to style it, display an alias and in another color like the datadog UI shows, but terraform does not seem to have that api, any ideas?

[Datadog UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJwwM.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.